# Colour heading on Form

Tags: forms-library, modern

I'm using the Forms Modern webpart in our Intranet but there is a little blue bar that show on top of the form. Does anybody know where this is coming from? Can I remove it or at least change the colour? This is the Form title placeholder but removing the title doesn't remove the blue bar, neither does changing the theme

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, this is magically fixed this morning. There is no longer a color header so if you have no title in the Form, it will show up a blank white. Thanks Microsoft!